# load ngController after ngApp is loaded by AJAX

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Just suppose I have a simple `html` file with `Angular.js` and `JQuery` loaded

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="#subPage"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadSubPage()" />
</body>
<script>
    var myModule = Angular.module('myApp',[]);
    function onclick() {
        $.get('somewhere/aPage.html', function (d,s,j) {
            $("#subPage").html(d);
        });
    }
</script>
```

and my `somewhere/aPage.html` is something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="blahCtrl">
    <span>{{message}}</span>
</div>
<script>
    myModule.controller('blahCtrl', function($scope) {
        console.log('This Is Not Printed Even!!!');
        $scope.message = 'The blah!';
    });
</script>
```

as you see, I want load my sub page after clicking on the button, it's OK! but it seems the controller doesn't run. because the message is not printed in console.

**what's the problem? why this doesn't work at all? what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use jQuery to accomplish this? I think in most cases, it makes more sense to simply leverage what Angular has to offer.

Comment: Yes exactly there is! unfortunately it's not my decide and I can't change it, some organization stupid rules...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding html code that your angular not aware of. you need to run compile after you change DOM elements externally see [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). Your code should be something like this (this is juse pseudo - you need to inject $compile and have a scope):

```
<script>
var myModule = Angular.module('myApp',[]);
function onclick() {
    $.get('somewhere/aPage.html', function (d,s,j) {
        $("#subPage").html(d);
         $compile($("#subPage"))(scope);
    });
}
```

Comment: This code started working only after adding `scope.$apply();` right after `$compile($("#subPage"))(scope);`

Answer (score 0):

why you not use **directive** like:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="#subPage"></div>
    <button type="button" load-sub-page/>
</body>
<script>
    var myModule = Angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myModule.directive("loadSubPage", function(){
      return{
         link : function(scope, ele, attr){
            ele.bind("click", function(){
                $.get('somewhere/aPage.html', function (d,s,j) {
                   scope.$apply(function(){
                       $("#subPage").html(d);
                    });
                 });
             })
          }
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like this solution doesn't work. At least a could make it work. Internally Angular's $apply() function triggers $digest() method - so, all watch listeners are fired, and the resulted output HTML is capable of reflecting current model data. However, any controllers passed with the Ajax data are not registered. And this is the problem for me...